# Pass parameter during instantiation of ip core in vivado

Tags: verilog, xilinx, vivado

Although it seems impossible from research:
[Passing parameter to xci core](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Design-Entry/Xilinx-fifo-core/m-p/438184/highlight/true#M5218)

I am designing a custom core which uses an instance of a Xilinx FIFO. However, the top module has parameters which are exposed in the IP Packager, and *should* modify the included FIFO core.

```
module top();
 parameter C_FIFO_DEPTH = 256
 xilinx_fifo_core #(
  .FIFO_DEPTH(C_FIFO_DEPTH)
) my_fifo_instance (...);
```

This way, when someone instantiates my module, by overriding parameter C_FIFO_DEPTH, they also change the embedded FIFO's depth.

Although this would work for user written modules, it doesn't work for instances of IP cores (xci), which seem to be configurable only through the "Customize IP" gui.

I have disabled Out-of-context generation, but still no dice.

I am currently working on a (very messy) solution using tcl scripts in the packaged core, however an elegant solution is desperately needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `XPM_FIFO_xxx` cores. Look in the UG953 Libraries Guide for docs and examples. You can also do it for RAM with `XPM_MEMORY_xxx`.

Comment: This may have come late :D But I tested it, and based on my little Zynq here at home, it seems to work!
I need to contact people at my (very old) job and tell them!

Comment: Just all I needed too! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any elegant solution, but here are three more messy ones:

(1) just use the largest FIFO you'll ever need. (Clearly likely to be a waste of area.)

(2) create a range of FIFOs of different sizes and use `generate case` to choose the right one. (Only any good if the range of useful sizes is reasonably limited.)

(3) don't use an IP block - design your own FIFO. (You probably thought of that.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
1.) Waste of area AND will lead to other issues - in my case this *may* be used commercially.
2.) Different sizes would be good, if they were discrete and specific. However, there is the case where the **width** may also change, leading to too many combinations and possibilities.
3.) Best case, but only defers the problem. Do I create all the IP blocks I will use?

Comment: @GCon I don't see how (3) defers the problem. If your FIFO is large enough to require a RAM, make sure you code it in a style such that Vivado infers a RAM. I don't see why it is necessary to use an IP block at all.

Comment: Sorry If I seemed hostile; I have been working on this for days. What I meant was that although you can possibly design a FIFO core and not use Xilinx's, this would be rather inefficient if you have to design custom hdl for all the ip cores you use. From, what I understand though, your answer is as close as possible. Either use TCL to hook changes to the parent core (the custom core) that will repackage the child IP (FIFO) with the changed parameters, or use a custom core (your suggestion). Since there is no way around this issue, I am accepting your proposal as the answer.